# inotifywait command to monitor files deleted

Tags: ubuntu-mate, inotify

This gives no notification if a file is deleted. It works with created files.

```
delete      file or directory deleted within watched directory
dir=/home/andy/Downloads/


inotifywait -m "$dir" --format '%w%f' -e create -e delete |
    while read file; do
        date +'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p' >> /home/andy/Downloads/New_Created_Files.txt
        echo New file downloaded OR created. >> /home/andy/Downloads/New_Created_Files.txt
        gxmessage -fg red -font  'sans 25' -timeout 3 ' File has been created,deleted, or moved to the specified directory.'
    done
```

Comment: is your delete command correct? https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-inotify/

Comment: @24601 Events:
 access  file or directory contents were read
 modify  file or directory contents were written
 attrib  file or directory attributes changed
 close_write file or directory closed, after being opened in
             writable mode
 close_nowrite file or directory closed, after being opened in
             read-only mode
 close  file or directory closed, regardless of read/write mode
 open  file or directory opened
 create  file or directory created within watched directory
 delete  file or directory deleted within watched directory

Comment: If this is more info for the question add it with edit not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
dir=/home/andy/Downloads/

inotifywait -m "$dir" --format '%w%f' -e create -e delete -e moved_to -e moved_from |
    while read file; do
        date +'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p' >> /home/andy/Downloads/New_Created_Files.txt
        echo New file downloaded OR created. >> /home/andy/Downloads/New_Created_Files.txt
        gxmessage -fg red -font  'sans 25' -timeout 3 ' File has been created,deleted, or moved to/out of the specified directory.'
    done
```